# Tomcat timesout when it's working

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

First of all - I'm really little experienced with servlets and all other Java EE stuff.

I am trying to make simple chat room, but before all I just tried making simple udp server and client. Everything works, except one thing that after 45 seconds tomcat timesout and turns off. I have only single contextListener which calls UDP server class.

Is it because i have no servlets, or ?..

Here's my UDP server class:

```
public UDPServer() {
    System.out.println("Constructor reached");
    try {
        connect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


 public void connect() throws Exception
 {
    int serverPort = 9123;
    System.out.println("Server is starting");
    DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(serverPort);
    System.out.println("Server started");
       byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
       byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
       while(true)
          {
             DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
             serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
             String sentence = new String( receivePacket.getData());
             System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + sentence);
             InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
             int port = receivePacket.getPort();
             String capitalizedSentence = sentence.toUpperCase();
             sendData = capitalizedSentence.getBytes();
             DatagramPacket sendPacket =
             new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, port);
             serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
             receiveData =  new byte[1024];
             sendData = new byte[1024];
          }
 }
```

Here's my simple contextListener

```
public class StartupServlet implements ServletContextListener {

// private static Logger logger = Logger.getAnonymousLogger(ApplicationListener.class);

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
       // logger.info("class : context destroyed");

    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        ServletContext context = servletContextEvent.getServletContext();
        ///// HERE You launch your class
        UDPServer udpserver = new UDPServer();
       // logger.info("myapp : context Initialized");
    }
```

}

And here's web.xml

```
<web-app>
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.chatroom.servlet.StartupServlet</listener-class>
</listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Your #conncet()-method is in a infinite loop. Therefore the #contextInitialized() Methode will never finish. Normally a tomcat has a start timeout. Within that period the startup procedure (--> context initializiation) has to be finished.
You don't need a webcontainer like tomcat, when you are programming sockets directly. 

A webcontainer executes a servlet, based on the received request. The mapping between request (e.g. calling a URL in your browser) and servlet is defined in the web.xml. That's not what your are doing right now.

Comment: Thanks. To mess around locally i know that i don't need any container or such, but eventually I want to move server to some external hosting (OpenShift for example) so eventually I will need some server like tomcat or maybe jBoss or something. For now i guess i will just running it on separate thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UDP server runs in the same thread as servlet initializer thread, and it has an infinite loop. So, the application can't start. Run UDPServer in a seperate thread.